# tns build doesn't reflect the latest code

Tags: nativescript

Sometimes when I do a "tns build" it doesn't reflect the latest code - at least the android apk file doesn't.

Is there a command similar to "clean" - to rebuild everything.

Similarly, sometimes if I've got "watch" enabled and testing on the emulator - the watcher detects code changes - but the app doesn't reflect the change. the app restarts but not the changes. Mostly has to do with CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced that problem, but doing a `tns platform remove ios` and `tns platform add ios` should clear out any lingering stuff (same for Android of course).

Comment: I got the same issue and removing/adding platform doesn't help.